# javascript eventlistener autoincrements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a dashboard with multiple eventlisteners and AJAX, which transfers data back and forth to a Python backend.  It works fine the first time.  The 2nd time I click the eventlistener function, I get two responses... the third time 3... I can reset it by reloading the page.  So I assume that somehow each time the AJAX comes back the eventlistener registers again.  I've done a bunch of searching and can't find a similar problem.  Here's the javascript code (including the google map api that I'm passing back to the server).

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/css/drunken-parrot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../static/css/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <div id="leftCol" class="bodyx">
          <form role="form">
              <placebutton class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" id="placebutton">Save</placebutton>
          </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function sendplace() {
    $('placebutton').click(function() {
        pete = ({"firstName":"John"});
        console.log("Test");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/new_place2',
            data: (pete),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        });
    });
    };
    var placebutton = document.querySelector("placebutton");
    placebutton.addEventListener("click", sendplace, false);
    console.log("addEvent");
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've whittled the file down thinking there might be some interference - I can't find anything - the entire file is here.  It still has the two problems - 1 - first click doesn't do anything, and 2 - it sends one more loop every time.  Hopefully this is easier to see...  Thanks again.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: SO when you click on button you are adding a click event to another button. If you click the button more than once you add multiple click events to that button.

Comment: How do I prevent that from happening?  Must be a very common thing?

Comment: Don't bind events inside other click events? Or unbind before you bind them?

Comment: Use jQuery, or don't use jQuery. Mixing the two (using `$().click` in one place and `addEventListener()` in another) is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan - I'm obviously pretty new to front-end.  I took out the $('placebutton') line and corresponding }); and it worked just fine. I appreciate the note.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the context, but clearly, you're attaching the listener each time ajax is done. Try replacing this:

```
placebutton.addEventListener("click", sendplace, false);
```

with this

```
placebutton.removeEventListener("click",sendplace);
placebutton.addEventListener("click", sendplace, false);
```

Mind you that this is not a very clean way to fix it. You should really figure out why `placebutton.addEventListener` is executed many times (or maybe it's added somewhere else in the code?).

Comment: try adding a console.count('placebutton click event attach') next to placebutton.addEventListener(...) and you'll see in the console how many times it gets executed

Comment: Thanks.  I've got the FireFox Inspect panel open to the console, and it automatically rolls up the identical events, so it clearly says "2" then "3"... another thing - the button doesn't work the first time after reload, only on the 2nd click, then gives 2 events (I get 2 new identical database entries on the server side), then each subsequent click adds another.  I added the 'removeEventListener' code like you mentioned and added a console log - it only runs at the first load. I added it again in the function and it keeps me to 2 events for every click...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikeMcCaughan for making it clear - I had a jQuery function wrapped inside of an addEventListener function.

Here's how this looks (working):

```
function sendplace() {
        var add1 = place;
        console.log(place);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/new_place2',
            data: JSON.stringify(place),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                window.alert("Saved!");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };
```

And the code that calls the function:

```
var placebutton = document.querySelector("placebutton");
placebutton.addEventListener("click", sendplace, false);
```